# How to fixate this div into this other div? It's a nav bar and it won't align vertically

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the n00b questions but here goes:

As seen in the screenshot, I can't align the text list items to the nav bar. Refer to the code so you can see what i'm talking about. It's a bit of a mess but what I basically have is a master div that holds the other divs in attempts to keep them "organized"

If anyone can help, it'd be great. thanks!

**Screenshot** here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwEnR.jpg

**HTML**

```
<div class="masterwrappernav">
    <div class="abovenav">
        <div class="logowrappers">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="slogan">
                <img src="img/1pyramid.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headernav">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#003B57;">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="articles/index.html">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="devotions/index.html">Devotions</a></li>
                <li><a href="biblestudy/index.html">Bible Study</a></li>
                <li><a href="schedule/index.html">Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href="store/index.html">Merchandise</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="donations/index.html" style="border-right:1px solid">Donations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.masterwrappernav {
    background-color:#11120D;
    width:100%;
    height:180px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.abovenav {
    background-image:url('/img/wtmot.png');
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    width:100%;
    height:140px;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #D6D6D6;
}

.headernav {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('/img/grad.png');
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #212121;
    text-align:center;
}

.nav {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul li {
    display:inline;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:19px;
}

.nav ul li a:link {
    border-left:1px solid;
    padding:9px 1%;
    background-image:url('/img/grad.png');
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    color:#454443;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fixed `height` of `40px` on your `.headernav`. Auto height can fix the alignment problem.

```
.headernav {
    height: auto;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want exact `40px` height for `.headernav` you can use this snippet below-

```
.nav ul {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav ul li a:link {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm actually curious as to why I need to put "margin-top:5px;". It works, I just don't know why lol

Comment: The `ul` has a default margin from browser. In google chrome it's `1em`. I just overwritten that to `5px` for better alignment. Try giving the `margin-top` of `0px` you will see the links are touching the top edge of your nav.

Answer (score 0):

you're messing around with "position: absolute;" without any need IMHO and your UL/LI get some auto-assigned margin/padding - use a RESET!
Look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdp70prj/1/) for a possible way to a solution.

CSS:

```
.masterwrappernav
{
background-color:#11120D;
height:180px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.abovenav
{
background-color:#f7f7f7;
height:140px;
margin:0 auto;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px #D6D6D6;
}
.headernav
{

background-color:#f7f7f7;
height:40px;
width:100%;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #212121;
text-align:center;
}

.nav
{

    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.nav li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.nav ul li
{
display:inline;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:19px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.nav ul li a:link
{
border-left:1px solid;
padding:9px 1%;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
color:#454443;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="masterwrappernav">
    <div class="abovenav">
        <div class="logowrappers">
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><!--<img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO">--></a></div>
    <div id="slogan"><!--<img src="img/1pyramid.png" alt="PYRAMID">--></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headernav">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#003B57;">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about/index.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="articles/index.html">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="devotions/index.html">Devotions</a></li><li><a href="biblestudy/index.html">Bible Study</a></li>
                    <li><a href="schedule/index.html">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store/index.html">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="donations/index.html" style="border-right:1px solid">Donations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```